# Replacing first occurrence of a specific pattern in Java

Tags: java, regex

My **input** is the following string:

`"<div>content <label class=\"ph\">$data</label> <label class=\"ph\">$data</label> <label class=\"ph\">$data</label> more content</div>"`
*(Where instead of $data there might be any string)*

And my **required output** is:
`"<div>content REPLACED <label class=\"ph\">$data</label> <label class=\"ph\">$data</label> more content</div>"`

Basically, replacing just the first occurrence of a pattern like:
`String regex = <label class=\"ph\">.*</label>`

But when trying to use:
`Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(contentInput).replaceFirst("");`

I'm getting:
`"<div>content REPLACED more content</div>"`

**Any Ideas of the correct regex to use, or any other idea?**
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with slash try using this pattern:

```
String regex = "<label class=\\\"ph\"\\>.*</label>"
```

This will match:
     `<label class=\"pH"\>ANYTHING</label>`

Where `\\` is used to print or match \
And `\"` is used to print or match "